# Log4j 1.2: %replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution} and %enc{pattern} not working

Tags: logging, log4j

Is %replace and %enc supported in log4j 1.2.x?. Relevant configurations were found in log4j 2.x documentation [1] but not for older versions.

[1] https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**
Features found in log4j 2 may not be found in log4j 1. According to their site:

> The API for Log4j 2 is not compatible with Log4j 1.x, however an
> adapter is available to allow applications to continue to use the
> Log4j 1.x API.
>
> http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/