# How to remove or replace newline from log messages log4j

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am using below conversion pattern

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z}  [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
```

but I want to remove new line characters.

I have tried using `%replace(%ex){'[\r\n]+', '\\n'}%nopex%n`

but it's not working %replace is not working. it only reading **%r** and then **eplace**

Comment: Let me know if you solved your problem. If you did, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer that worked for you, or add your own answer explaining how you solved it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. None of the below mentioned suggestion helped.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you were not using the right syntax of the `%replace` - see [Log4j Layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) for the right one.

Using the right syntax, you could remove all the newlines using the following expression:

```
%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{}
```

However, removing newlines altogether can make the log hard to read in certain cases. I would suggest that, instead of removing, you replace the newlines with something, e.g. with such an [arrow character: ↵](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21B5/index.htm) (I chose it for its similarity with the symbol on the [Enter key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key)).

So I would suggest using such a pattern:

```
%replace{%msg}{\r?\n}{↵}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing is good and all, but there's also a dedicated function for that.

```
%enc{%m}{CRLF}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Tomasz Linkowski suggestion is to add the new line at the end

```
%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]}{}%n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Warning: May not work for Log4J v1

I also had the same problem, and after investigating it I found that the `%replace` option is not exist on log4j 1.x.

The link that @Tomasz added for [log4j layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) is for log4j 2.x (you can see the version in top of the page on left side).

In addition, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232714/log4j-1-2-replacepatternregexsubstitution-and-encpattern-not-working) answer you can understand that not all options from log4j 2.x are available on 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to the original question. The problem is about log4j2 using html entities in replace substitution string. So instead of \n you should use -> &#10;
So the answer is exactly like below ->

%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{&#10;}

I've spent so much time figuring it out. Finally solved!. I'm sharing for anyone else not wasting the same amount of time. :)

Comment: Why would you want to replace newline with newline? The question is about how to remove newline.

Comment: Yes, the question is about removing new line. I realized that later. But if you want to remove and add a replacement with new line and some stuff, in this case any source on the internet or official doc does not show how to do it. I found it out by reading and trying based on sources. So anyone who wants to replace can easily find the solution, I have put my answer.